# is it possible pass data between two different browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser, pass-data

I have to pass data between two different browser windows *(* **Eg:** Chrome , Firefox *)*.

But the two browser windows does not have any *parent window*.

**Assumption:** Suppose if I know one browser window name , is it possible to get the data from other browser?

Its is an **R&D**.

Comment: yoou mean between chrom and firefox?

Comment: betwwen chrome-chrome or firefox -chrome?

Comment: [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) might be helpful if you want to communicate between two separate browsers without a server.

Comment: @Ethaan & Naeem between two different browsers.

Answer (score 3):

**Server Option using (node.js)**

If you are open to use `node.js` i suggest you to take a look on [Socket.io](http://socket.io).

They have a pretty good example of how to communicate on 2 or more browser using the chat example.

Take a look on this [demo](http://socket.io/demos/chat/)

**Only Client option (using webRTC)**

Also if you don't wanna get mess with the server.

Take a quickly look into [this post](http://blog.printf.net/articles/2013/05/17/webrtc-without-a-signaling-server/)

**Update**

Seems like the only option we have here its [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/architecture)

Take a look into this 2 SO.

[Can HTML5 Websockets connect 2 clients (browsers) directly without using a server? (P2P)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277351/can-html5-websockets-connect-2-clients-browsers-directly-without-using-a-serve)

[Do websockets allow for p2p (browser to browser) communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118272/do-websockets-allow-for-p2p-browser-to-browser-communication)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the communication between two different browser using [HTML5 WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets)

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But I think websocket is used to push the data from the server to client browser . How it is possible to send the data between two browsers ?